# OpenCv: cv2.HoughCircles inconsistent behavior

Tags: python, opencv

I was testing `cv2.HoughCircles()` (**OpenCv version 2.4.9**) on a simple image with the following parameters:

```
cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
dp=1.7, 
minDist=180, 
minRadius=55.
```

I got 2 circles: one of radius 87.4696 and the other 80.4787.

Then on the same image, I used again that function with the same set of parameters but this time adding `maxRadius = 100` (which shouldn't matter in that case since the 2 detected circles are having a radius < 100).

As a result I only got 1 detected circle with a radius of 84.6768. What gives?

Anyone having a clue on what might go wrong here?

Original image:

[image]

Comment: First of all, are both of the circles correct w.r.t. your image?

Comment: Yup, both circles were correctly detected. Sorry for not posting the images but I don't have enough "reputation" to post images. :-/

Comment: please provide the links for your input images so others can experiment it.

Comment: Done (link added to the original message).